# using preg_match and preg_replace

Tags: php, url, preg-replace, preg-match

I have two strings like:

`http://localhost/web/`

and

`http://localhost/web/category/`

which sometimes become:

`http://localhost/web/2/`, `http://localhost/web/3/` etc....

and

`http://localhost/web/category/2/`, `http://localhost/web/category/3/` etc...

I want to make a verification and:

If the link is `http://localhost/web/` it remains the same.

If the link is `http://localhost/web/2/` it becomes `http://localhost/web/`

If the link is `http://localhost/web/category/` it remains the same.

If the link is `http://localhost/web/category/2/` it becomes `http://localhost/web/category/`

I guess it should be done using `preg_replace()` and `preg_match()`.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you meant "ht-tp" literally or if you are just writing it that way so links won't get created?

Comment: it's just to prevent automatic links

Comment: @mohamed87, you can just format sample links as source code (use the 0101010 toolbar button).

Comment: what 0101010 toolbar button is?
and I think my question is clear enough. ht-tp is http but to prevent automatic linking in stackoverflow. if you read my question I'm saying that I want to remove the page numbers so that links in a category will become with no page numbers.

Comment: @OP: you might think about adding the tag 'regex'. Also, as a suggestion, "http" as-is would have been fine. Automatic links or Writing them as source code would have been less confusing. Just a suggestion. Also, a three line write-up (lines 12, 13, and 14) would have been sufficient as a description. The rest was quite superfluous. This will make it easier going forward for others to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I fixed the URLs so they display as plain text without the need for that `-` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the regular expression you will need:

```
(http:\/\/localhost\/)(web|web\/category)\/([\d]+)\/
```

For the preg_replace function, you will need a replacement statement which will re-write the string based on your criteria:

```
'$1$2'
```

The above replacement statement essentially concatenates the first capture group (first set of parens which evaluates to http://localhost/) with the second capture group of either 'web' or 'web/category'. Since we don't care about the last capture group ($3), we don't add it to the replacement statement; however, we could since we are capturing it. If you don't want to capture it, replace this "([\d]+)" with "[\d]+".

The following is sample code which incorporates the pattern with the replacement to form a full preg_replace statement:

```
<?php

$pattern = '@(http:\/\/localhost\/)(web|web\/category)\/([\d]+)\/@i';

$subjects = array(
    'http://localhost/web/2/',
    'http://localhost/web/category/2/'
);

foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    echo sprintf('Original: %s, Modified: %s', $subject, preg_replace($pattern, '$1$2', $subject)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Toss the above code into a file (for example: replace.php) and run it via the command-line:

```
php replace.php
```